# Changing a SQL query to a linq query - syntax

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm having problem coding my linq query.

This is my SQL query:

```
select 
    price, (cast(sum(Quantity) as decimal(7,2)))
from 
    OrderDetails
where 
    ItemID = 1000
group by 
    price
order by 
    price
```

This is my linq query:

```
var result = from od in db.OrderDetails
             where od.ItemID == 1000
             orderby od.Price
             group by price
             select od.price, (cast(sum(od.Quantity) as decimal(7, 2)));
```

This linq query seems to be incorrect. What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:
(You need to move the order part to be after the grouping)

```
var q = (from o in context.OrderDetails
            where o.ItemID == 1000
            group o by o.price into grp
            select new
            {
                Price = grp.Key,
                Quantity = grp.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
            }).OrderBy(a => a.Price);
```